# unable to insert the data in my database

Tags: mysql, struts2

I am new to Struts2.
i created a some class file to insert the data in database(MySQL).
when i insert the data i got the error. the error is

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of
>   parameters, which is 0).

i am not able to understand that how it occur and how to resolve it.

RegistrationService.java

```
 PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(sql);   
                        sql = "insert into registration(first_name,last_name) value(?,?)";
                            p.setString(1,registration.first_name);
                            p.setString(2,registration.last_name);
```

Registration.java

```
    public class Registration extends ActionSupport{
       String  first_name;
       String last_name;
//getter and setter
```

RegistrationAction.java

```
public String execute() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    RegistrationService registrationservice= new RegistrationService();
    if(registrationservice.filledRegistration(registration)){
    return "registered";
    }
    return "failed";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss on this lines:

> PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(sql);
>
> sql = "insert into registration(first_name,last_name) value(?,?)";

To correct it please see below:

> sql = "insert into registration(first_name,last_name) value(?,?)";
>
> PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(sql);

Comment: ya..i did it..but i am not able to see my inserted data in my database..what the reason behind

Comment: where you able to follow this? http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.sql/PreparedStatementsetStringintparameterIndexStringx.htm

Comment: I think you forgot to add this line p.executeUpdate();

Comment: i already did that. even i kept in try catch block. and proper open and closing of statemnt. but then also i didnt get any inserted data in my databse